# A way to refer to the "Current cell" for a dynamic Conditional Formatting in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, cell, conditional-formatting

To be more specific, I want the Conditional Formatting to check the content of the cell that is currently being formatted and be dynamic as I copy-paste the Conditional Formatting into another cell, without having to manually fiddle with the formula again.

So what I'm doing is this (using an example):

I have a list of foods categorized by type (Fruits, vegetables, etc...) and every week the list changes, so its not possible to add "hard values" to formulas, it has to be a cell reference under the category.

Which means that under the category "fruits" for example, in week 1 i can have: banana, apple and peach but totally different fruits another week.

Anyways, I also want to create a calendar with the days in the week, where I put 4 drop-down menus which correspond to the 4 types of food. The drop down menus update as I update the initial list of avaiable foods.

**Now down to the real issue.**

I want that the cell used for the drop down menu to take an specific color when the content of that cell contains a food inside a given category.

For example, I select Apple, it checks for the apple and applies the apple color to the cell.

I acheived this with this

=COUNTIF(A4:A6, INDIRECT("RC","FALSE"))

*I found someone online using the INDIRECT("RC","FALSE") value to "reference" the current cell but its not working for me...*

A4:A6 is the range of fruits and it will give the red color to the apple because i defined it in Conditionnal formatting.

Now when I copy the conditional formatting is not working for the other apples and I want to make it work for others, just by checking if the current cell contains a value in a range of cells, without manually changing the current cell for every cell.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15trOcNzucTJDDwuseQTsvjhioIGN9W4NEjhztmMZ1so/edit#gid=0

This is my google spreadsheet, please help ! I'm not sure if I can understand better. This is for a much bigger project and really need the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current cell for conditional formatting is left top most cell in `Apply to range` range.
In your case it is `D11`. So you should use following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$4:$A$6, D11)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @basic! This worked for my case! I have one column having "IDs" for projects and anytime one of those ID numbers are entered into my other column "ID Dependency" (project that require another to be complete before starting), that ID number in the "ID" column with format as desired. It works on the whole column of IDs!